# Having KeyError: 'sum" in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keyerror

I am getting a KeyError: 'sum' and I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.

```
def conversion(self, data):
    result = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(['category', 'pred']).size()).rename(columns={0: 'count'}).reset_index()
    total_count = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(['category']).sum()).rename(columns={0: 'sum'}).reset_index()
    result = pd.merge(result, total_count, how='left', on=['category'])
    result['percentage'] = result.apply(lambda x: x['count']/x['sum']*100, axis=1)
    result['CategoryID'] = result['category'].replace({'En': 1, 'Go': 2, 'So': 3})
    return result
```

Am I doing something wrong in this line of code?

```
result['percentage'] = result.apply(lambda x: x['count']/x['sum']*100, axis=1)
```

Comment: apply is expecting a column `sum` in the dataframe result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suspect you wanted `x.count()` and `x.sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result['percentage'] = result.apply(lambda x: (x.count()/x.sum())*100, axis=1)
```